# Service for migration to parse-free equivalent plan

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, heroku, parse-platform, cloud

I have a non-commercial small project built on top of Parse Server. I really like it and don't want it to die, but since it makes me no money I don't want to spend anything on it neither.

Free plan of Parse suits me tottally. 30req/s is ok for me (I don't even cross 5req/s I guess).

Is there a service which supports Parse migration that can allow me to stay on the same (or at least close) pricing policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Azure [announced](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/announcing-the-publication-of-parse-server-with-azure-managed-services/) support for Parse. Azure App Service does have [free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) plans but there will probably be some minimal costs (probably pennies) for ancillary storage services and bandwidth. I would suggest starting a 1 month free Azure [trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/free-trial/) and seeing how it goes if you don't already have Azure credits through an MSDN subscription.

Comment: Just in case somebody will want to DDoS me or something, can I put a limit there, so it will work like a Parse (queueing every request above 30req/s until next second)?

Comment: @s1ddok my recollection is that the free tier will cut you off after you exhaust the free limits mentioned on the free plan link above. Someone can chile on and correct me if I'm wrong. Of course you can choose a higher tier and setup auto-scale if you are willing to open your wallet more to avoid this. And there are some DDoS protections built into Azure that should prevent this type of issue for clearly malicious traffic.

Comment: So I can put a limit after free period expires? I don't use any Microsoft services, so I'm afraid to start using one.

Comment: @s1ddok yes you can cancel after the free trial month

Comment: ugh, I just saw pricing plans there, doesn't seem to be pennies. I will going to spend around 10$ per month.

Comment: @s1ddok free plan plus a few pennies for storage and bandwidth is what I meant. If you use App Service standard or premium tier then it's not pennies.